# Is this C++ code portable? (assuming multidimensional arrays have continuous memory layout)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array, portability

First of all, sorry for my english if i make any grammar mistakes, etc ...

My question is, that when we have a two dimensional array, then if i am right, from the point of the computer and C/C++, it's just a long one dimensional array, the indices are just helping the compiler to map to the concrete address.

This code fragment works in Visual C++, however I would like to know, whether this code is **portable** and **conforms** *to the* **standard** (C++98), not causing surprises on other architectures and/or operating systems:

```
int arr[][3] = { 1, 5, 3, 7, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9 };
const int ARR_NUM = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);

int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(arr);    // NOT: int(*)[][3] !!!
for (int i = 0; i < ARR_NUM; ++i) {
    cout << ptr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: I switched tags since the tag wiki for [multidimensional] says to use [multidimensional-array] instead. I would suggest that replacing [arrays] with [language-lawyer] may attract the right folks.

Comment: I would use int* p= &arr[0][0] instead of reinterpret cast

Comment: @user396672, `int * p = arr[0];` is the same as `int * p = &arr[0][0];`, but is definitely clearer.

Comment: @Griwes: of course, it's the same, but &arr[0][0] stands for "address of the first int" and one don't need to count indirecions :) Although it's rather a matter of taste...

Comment: @user396672: ...while `arr[0];` is already of type `int[N]`, which can be used as `int *` - "conversion" from array to pointer is still obvious. `&arr[0][0]` mangles the code, making it a bit less readable (as usage of every operator, in most cases...).

Comment: @Griwes: Generally, concise != readable. For instance, I always prefer &arr[i] instead of array+i since the expression &arr[i] clearly state that arr is an array, I don't need to go to arr definition to understand what happens here (aside of the fact that pointer arithmetic is one of most disputable features of C and C++). I perfectly undestand you point but int * p = arr[0] is less clear for me: to understand it I need a few seconds; to understand &arr[0][0] I need hundreds of milliseconds :)

Comment: @user396672, then you are weird (no offence) :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Standardese

The elements of the multidimensional array are stored sequentially in row-major order, so the manual indexing is portable:

C++98, 8.3.4/1:

> An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty
>   set of N sub-objects of type T.

Obviously for a multidimensional array this applies recursively.

However, this use of `reinterpret_cast` is not portable. The standard says (C++98, 5.2.10/1) that

> [...] otherwise, the result is an rvalue and the [...],
>   array-to-pointer, [...] standard conversions are performed on the
>   expression v.

In other words, passing `arr` immediately triggers a decay of the array to a pointer to its first element. Then (C++98, 5.2.10/3) comes the catch-all

> The mapping performed by `reinterpret_cast` is implementation-defined.

The rest of the section lists a number of exceptions to this, specifying casts that are always well-defined. Seeing as none of them applies here, the conclusion is that technically it's implementation-defined by default.

### Final conclusion

Theoretically speaking, this is not portable. Practically, as long as the architectures are the same (e.g. x86) I would certainly expect the cast to work reliably.

Fortunately you don't have to assume anything like that because as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618931/50079) [have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618473/is-this-c-code-portable-assuming-multidimensional-arrays-have-continuous-mem/10618866#comment13760969_10618473), something like `int* ptr = arr[0]` does the same thing and is guaranteed portable.

Comment: Not sure this is the right quote: it speaks of `T1` and `T2` being objects, which I think is specifically different from pointer.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: True, I missed that -- arrays are POD so not the right quote. Still looking for something better.

Comment: According to Bjarne Stroustrup's book, reinterpret_cast is implementation-defined, because it works by creating the new destination pointer-type, and copies the bit pattern from the source type to it. Why it's implementation-defined its because this can cause alignment-changes and on some systems the number of bytes can be different between different pointer types. This doesn't means (from my point of view) that reinterpret_cast is not portable. In this situation, this conversion is implementation-defined, but semantically meaningful and should yield the same behavior among different systems.

Comment: Section 8.3.4 is the correct section, it strictly defines the memory layout of arrays such that the code in question is portable. Also note that _object_ refers to any memory entry, so it applies to all types (it does not mean class-type).

Comment: @Benj: You were not only asking about the portability, but also about whether it complies to the standard

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: If you are referring to 5.2.10/7, I think the wording there is sneaky. First it mentions "pointer to an object" which means pointer to anything as you say, but a little later it says "where T1 and T2 are *object types*" which IMHO refers to non-POD only.

Comment: @bames53: No, there can be no padding. "Contiguously" means no padding between `int`s to begin with, and then recursively it means no padding between the `int[]`s, etc.

Comment: @Jon There's no padding between int's in an array, and no padding between int[]'s in an array. But is `sizeof(int[n])` guaranteed to be `n * sizeof(int)`? Objects in an array can be contiguous without the last sub-object from one being contiguous with the first sub object of another.

Comment: @bames53: It's an array of arrays. Items in each sub-array are contiguous, and sub-arrays themselves are also contiguous (for the same reason: the whole thing is an array of sub-arrays, so the sub-arrays must be contiguous). Therefore the ints themselves are contiguous across sub-arrays.

Comment: That doesn't follow. Imagine an array of As has the structure: `AAApadding`. Note that all the As are contiguous as required. Now an array of these arrays is `AAApaddingAAApaddingAAApaddingmaybemorepadding`. Again, all the array elements are contiguous. But stepping from the last A in one subarray does not step to the first A in the next.

Comment: The only thing I see in the standard indicating that there's no padding is a statement that "This implies that the size of an array of n elements is n times the size of an element." However, I don't see that this is actually implied by the standard.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be really strict, reinterpret_cast is not terribly well defined in the standard. This will work everywhere, but you could make a pedantic case against it.

Use

```
int *ptr = arr[0];
```

to be on the very safe side. The contiguous array layout is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

As for the assumption, that multidimensional arrays have continuous memory layout it is standards conformant and portable. It is true ever since the times of C, and C++ does not change this.

However, `reinterpret_cast` isn't portable, so overall your code isn't guaranteed to work everywhere.

Comment: First, that's C, not C++. Second, that paragraph talks about array subscription. `reinterpret_case` should be implementation-defined in this case, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken `reinterpret_cast` is not a portable operation.

Comment: it depends. Some uses of `reinterpret_cast` are perfectly specified.