# Shuffling a matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, stl, shuffle

I need to randomly fill a matrix with a given number of a certain value. (For some reason I have a `C` 2D array). The simple solution I found was to interpret the 2D array as a 1D array: (please ignore the hard coded constants and ad hoc random objects):

```
int m[10][10] = {};

std::fill_n(&m[0][0], 24, -1);
std::shuffle(&m[0][0], &m[0][0] + 100, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

But this seems to be controversial as whether or not it is Undefined Behavior:

[Is it legal to access a bidimensional array as if it where a one-dimensional one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761624/is-it-legal-to-access-a-bidimensional-array-as-if-it-where-a-one-dimensional-one)

[May I treat a 2D array as a contiguous 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269099/may-i-treat-a-2d-array-as-a-contiguous-1d-array)

The gist is that even if the underlying data is guaranteed to be contiguous without padding between rows, the indexing scheme or incrementing the `&m[0][0]` `int*` pointer outside of the first row is invalid.

So I am searching for an alternate safe method. Is there a simple way to fill and then shuffle the 2D array without creating a 1D array and then copying it in the matrix?

Note: the rest of the matrix is all `0` so it is not needed to preserve those cells.

Comment: `Is there a simple way to fill and then shuffle the 2D array without creating a 1D array`. Assuming you have filled the array, to shuffle it, why not randomly generate i1 ,i2, j1, j2 where i and j are the limits of the rows and columns. Now interchange the values at these indices. Do this say 2000 times and it should be pretty alright

Comment: @bholagabbar ok... I think I would need to make sure not to generate duplicate pairs

Comment: Naah that's alright. i and j being the same, assuming your matrix is sufficiently large will occur very few number of times

Comment: @bholagabbar oh.. sry now I see what you are saying. Yeah, I guess it would work. (the matrix is small)

Comment: If you really want, you can maintain two `std::set`s which store already encountered `i` and `j`. If both of them exist in both the sets, regenerate the pair

Comment: @bholagabbar if (i,k) and (p,j) have been added, then your set solution will say don't add (i,j) which is wrong

Comment: no, no, I misunderstood the firs time. Duplicates are a non-issue actually, as it will be repeated a significant amount of times.

Comment: I've put my comments as an answer. Hope this idea works for you!

Comment: @bolov you are right about the duplicates part. You can maintain an `std::set<pair<int, int> >` to store the duplicate indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your 2d array is of dimensions *m X n*, it is initialized, and you'd like to do an in-place random shuffle.

It is very easy to modify the [Durstenfeld variant of the Fisher-Yates Shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) for this. Following is the pseudocode:

```
for i = m * n - 1 downto 1
    j = random integer in the range [0, i] (both inclusive)
    swap(a[i / n][i % n], a[j / n][j % n])
```

This is essentially the original algorithm, treating the array as 1d. Whenever indices *i* and *j* are chosen, though, the translation to row + column is made for each before acting on it.

Comment: Shuffling must be done this way -- using naive ad-hoc algorithms usually causes some shuffled outcomes to be more likely than others.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way to fill and then shuffle the 2D array without creating a 1D array

Sure. Assuming you have filled the array, to shuffle it, why not randomly generate `i1` ,`i2`, `j1`, `j2` where i and j are the *limits* of the rows and columns. Now interchange the values at these indices. Do this say *0.5 x no.of.rows x no.of.cols* , which is just a very rough figure. Essentially feel free to randomize it as much as you like. Anything less than `10^8` should be fine.

If you are worried generating duplicate pairs(which shouldn't really be a problem with larger matrices) you can maintain an `std::set<pair<int, int> >` which stores the indices generated. Whenever you generate `i` and `j`, check if `{i, j}` exists. If it does, regenerate it.

Answer (score 1):

you can choose a bijective function between an integer (your 1-D) index and the (i,j) pair, so this will be the way of treating your matrix as 1-D array. This is called a 'numbering scheme'.

Something like:

`oneDindex(rowIndex,colIndex)=colIndex*rowCount+rowIndex;`

inverse transform

```
rowIndex=oneDIndex % rowCount

colIndex=oneDIndex / rowCount;
```

So, you pick two 1D indexes at random in [0, rowCount*colCount) that you want exchanged, get their (rowIndex, colIndex) by the inverse transform and exchange them. Repeat until satisfied.

Comment: I know about this function. But I would need to create a iterator-wrapper object. If you ever tried to create an iterator class in C++ you know that is far from simple.

Comment: Do you really need to use std::shuffle? You said you have a C array that need shuffling - why don't you code your own shuffle algo on top of that? It will certainly be easier than to write an iterator. Note: the 'why' question is really a question, not a critique in disguise, I am interested in an answer.

Comment: Before you added the last paragraph I thought you meant to use these transformations in order to use `std::shuffle`. You are right, I don't need to use `std::shuffle`. Your solution is OK.